# Reading from a protected page in MediaWiki with a Bot User

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api

Using an admin user I created a dedicated user to own the bot; I added this bot to the 'Bots' group. With this user I logged in and created a [BotPassword](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Bot_passwords) for my app, and have granted it *every possible permission* a Bot can have.

I have the following config options defined in my `LocalSettings.php`

```
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['read'] = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['bot']['read'] = true;
```

From my app, I get can successfully login using the [Login API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Login#Method_1._login) - after getting the tokens:

*Logging In*

```
{
    "login": {
        "result":"Success",
        "lguserid":11,
        "lgusername":"botuser@example.org"
    }
}
```

However, using the following parameters to query for a page:

```
ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair> queryParameters = new ArrayList<>();
queryParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "query"));
queryParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("prop", "revisions"));
queryParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rvprop", "content"));
queryParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("format", "json"));
queryParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("formatversion", "2"));
queryParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rvslots", "main"));
queryParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("titles", pageName));
```

I get the error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code":"readapidenied",
        "info":"You need read permission to use this module.",
        "docref":"See https://wiki.example.org/api.php for API usage. Subscribe to the mediawiki-api-announce mailing list at &lt;https://lists.wikimedia.org/mailman/listinfo/mediawiki-api-announce&gt; for notice of API deprecations and breaking changes."
    }
}
```

If I give global read permissions in LocalSettings,

```
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['read'] = true;
```

Then my bot user is able to fetch the pages without any errors -

---

How can I grant permissions to this bot such that I can query for the contents of a page without getting a **readapidenied** error, while still keeping my Wiki private? Is the BotPassword account in different groups then the main user? If so, how can I change the groups of the bot?

I am running `MediaWiki: 1.32.0` on `PHP: 7.2.16` and I use [ImapAuthorization](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ImapAuthorization) for user login.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set in Special:BotPasswords what permissions the bot can access. The idea is that your bot password will be stored less securely than your real password (probably included in some bot config file on some shared server) so you'll want to limit what it can be used for.

Comment: I forgot to add that I have granted the Bot every permission available on the Bot Passwords page. Is there something I am missing in the `Special:ListGrants` page?

Comment: That should work in theory then. It sounds like there is some mistake in the group configuration, or the bot is in the wrong group.

Comment: Any thoughts on how I can check this? Should I be relying on the session cookie for auth? Or should I have another token for the read request?

Comment: Try calling the userinfo API, that will tell you if you are logged in with the right user and whether it has the right groups. You can check what rights the group has via Special:ListGroupRights.

Comment: Looks like I might have an issue in my HTTP session framework, the call to get my user info appears to show me an anonymous user. I am trying to switch to one of the already built client libraries.